# How to build something like litmus.com or emailonacid.com

Tags: architecture, software-design

How do you start building something like litmus.com or emailonacid.com where you can view one email on multiple email clients automatically, I know we can use virtual machines/simulators but how do you automate the process of capturing snapshots of the email on multiple clients like gmail for android, apple mail, outlook on windows etc.

1. How do you generate a new email for each user
2. How do you login with that email on multiple devices for each user
3. How do you view emails sent to that email on multiple devices

I just need a starting point for all this please any help would be helpful. Thanks.